# How to sucessfully send a .bin file via serial communication to another device using QT creator?

Tags: qt, user-interface, serial-port, putty, file-transfer

I am trying to send and successfully install a .bin file (that contains a required software) using QT through a service adaptor to a device. I am just trying to achieve the same function as extraPuTTY service terminal does. The .bin file I am trying to send is successfully possible via extraPuTTY even though it utilizes the YMODEM protocol. However this is not being achieved when I tried to send the same .bin file via my QT code I developed.
In QT , I am just trying to open the file , read and send it via serial port. Is it necessary to implement a YMODEM Protocol like extraPuttY does for successful file transfer and installation to take place?